# I cant access property of relationship collections in a Livewire

Tags: laravel, relationship

How to access the properties of this in a livewire controller?

When I do:

```
dd($this->task->updates->files);
```

I get this error:

> Property [files] does not exist on this collection instance.

But when I do:

```
dd($this->task->updates);
```

I see all collection with file names.

I need to read the

```
$this->task->updates->files
```

because store the filenames for a function to download S3 disk.

The model updates has:

```
public function task(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you have a collection of multiple objects. you can not use relation on collection. You need to iterate that collection and then use property `->files` on that iteration.

Comment: yes, that was the problem, i think was a livewire problem reading binding data..my bad..Thx!